# Should I make private IBOutlet internal in order to unit test?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I'm trying to run tests on UIButtons that I have connected as IBOutlets in my class. However, they are all set to private as there's no need for them to be accessible by other classes. Should I make them internally accessible for testing by removing the private keyword or is there a better way to test them?

Comment: The question is, do you really want to test them?

Comment: @Sulthan I want to be able to sequentially "press" the buttons and make sure that certain things happen and certain things don't happen. However, I've set the IBOutlets and their IBActions to private. Just wondering if it's a bad thing to open up these properties and methods just for testing purposes.

Comment: Consider this - what you want to write is a UI test (an integration test) and for a UI test, you don't need the specific references to views, you can find them using queries. See https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/ui-testing-in-xcode-7-part-1-ui-testing-gotchas/

Answer (score -1):

XCTest has access to all those methods. Try just writing the test assuming that and see what you get. You should not need to remove the `private` keyword.